# Java video output can only be opened using Quicktime but no other media player can open it

Tags: java, video, jpeg, jmf, mov

I have a program and that captures the screen and then takes those images and turns them into a movie. (Using the JpegImagesToMovies.java that was customized to work with .png) I have tried multiple extensions: `.mov`, `.mp4`, `.avi` (I am open to trying others).  However, regardless of what extension I use, when I try to open the file with Windows Media Player I get the following error:

> Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file. 
>   Error code [C00D11B1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/c00d11b1)

I've also tried opening the file using VLC but that produces the following error:

> No suitable decoder module:
>   VLC does not support the audio or video format "twos". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

Opening the file using QuickTime does work.

So the question is, **how can I produce a video file that can be opened with most if not all media players**.

---

Here is my JpegImagesToMovie.java

```
package maple;

/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.datasink.*;
import javax.media.format.RGBFormat;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;

/**
 * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
 * QuickTime movie.
 */
public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

        static private Vector<String> getImageFilesPathsVector(
                        String imagesFolderPath) {
                File imagesFolder = new File(imagesFolderPath);
                String[] imageFilesArray = imagesFolder.list();
                Vector<String> imageFilesPathsVector = new Vector<String>();
                for (String imageFileName : imageFilesArray) {
                        if (!imageFileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("png"))
                                continue;
                        imageFilesPathsVector.add(imagesFolder.getAbsolutePath()
                                        + File.separator + imageFileName);
                }
                return imageFilesPathsVector;
        }

        public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                        Vector<String> inFiles, MediaLocator outML) {
                ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
                                inFiles);

                Processor p;

                try {
                        System.err
                                        .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
                        p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
                        return false;
                }

                p.addControllerListener(this);

                // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
                // some processing options on the processor.
                p.configure();
                if (!waitForState(p, Processor.Configured)) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
                        return false;
                }

                // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
                p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                                FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));// FileTypeDescriptor.MSVIDEO

                // Query for the processor for supported formats.
                // Then set it on the processor.
                TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
                Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
                if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
                        System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                                        + tcs[0].getFormat());
                        return false;
                }

                tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

                System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

                // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
                // realize it.
                p.realize();
                if (!waitForState(p, Controller.Realized)) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
                        return false;
                }

                // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
                DataSink dsink;
                if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                                                        + outML);
                        return false;
                }

                dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
                fileDone = false;

                System.err.println("start processing...");

                // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
                try {
                        p.start();
                        dsink.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("IO error during processing");
                        return false;
                }

                // Wait for EndOfStream event.
                waitForFileDone();

                // Cleanup.
                try {
                        dsink.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                p.removeControllerListener(this);

                System.err.println("...done processing.");

                return true;
        }

        /**
         * Create the DataSink.
         */
        DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

                DataSource ds;

                if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
                        return null;
                }

                DataSink dsink;

                try {
                        System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
                        dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
                        dsink.open();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
                        return null;
                }

                return dsink;
        }

        Object waitSync = new Object();
        boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

        /**
         * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
         * false if the transition failed.
         */
        boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
                synchronized (waitSync) {
                        try {
                                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                                        waitSync.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                }
                return stateTransitionOK;
        }

        /**
         * Controller Listener.
         */
        public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

                if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                                || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                                || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitSync) {
                                stateTransitionOK = true;
                                waitSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitSync) {
                                stateTransitionOK = false;
                                waitSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
                        evt.getSourceController().stop();
                        evt.getSourceController().close();
                }
        }

        Object waitFileSync = new Object();
        boolean fileDone = false;
        boolean fileSuccess = true;

        /**
         * Block until file writing is done.
         */
        boolean waitForFileDone() {
                synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                        try {
                                while (!fileDone)
                                        waitFileSync.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                }
                return fileSuccess;
        }

        /**
         * Event handler for the file writer.
         */
        public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

                if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                                fileDone = true;
                                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                                fileDone = true;
                                fileSuccess = false;
                                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                // changed this method a bit

                if (args.length == 0)
                        prUsage();

                // Parse the arguments.
                int i = 0;
                int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = -1;
                Vector<String> inputFiles = new Vector<String>();
                String rootDir = null;
                String outputURL = null;

                while (i < args.length) {

                        if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                // new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                                frameRate = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

                        } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                outputURL = args[i];
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-i")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                rootDir = args[i];

                        } else {
                                System.out.println(".");
                                prUsage();
                        }
                        i++;
                }

                if (rootDir == null) {
                        System.out
                                        .println("Since no input (-i) forder provided, assuming this JAR is inside JPEGs folder.");
                        rootDir = (new File(".")).getAbsolutePath();
                }
                inputFiles = getImageFilesPathsVector(rootDir);

                if (inputFiles.size() == 0)
                        prUsage();
                if (outputURL == null) {
                        outputURL = (new File(rootDir)).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                                        + "pngs2movie.mov";
                }
                if (!outputURL.toLowerCase().startsWith("file:///")) {
                        outputURL = "file:///" + outputURL;
                }

                // Check for output file extension.
                if (!outputURL.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mov")) {
                        prUsage();
                        outputURL += ".mov";
                        System.out
                                        .println("outputURL should be ending with mov. Making this happen.\nNow outputURL is: "
                                                        + outputURL);
                }

                if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
                        prUsage();
                        System.out.println("Trying to guess movie size from first image");
                        BufferedImage firstImageInFolder = getFirstImageInFolder(rootDir);
                        width = firstImageInFolder.getWidth();
                        height = firstImageInFolder.getHeight();
                        System.out.println("width = " + width);
                        System.out.println("height = " + height);
                }

                // Check the frame rate.
                if (frameRate < 1)
                        frameRate = 30;

                // Generate the output media locators.
                MediaLocator oml;

                if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
                        System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
                        System.exit(0);
                }

                JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
                imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

                System.exit(0);
        }

        private static BufferedImage getFirstImageInFolder(String rootDir) {
                File rootFile = new File(rootDir);
                String[] list = (rootFile).list();
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
                for (String filePath : list) {
                        if (!filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")
                                        && !filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
                                continue;
                        }
                        try {
                                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(rootFile
                                                .getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + filePath));
                                break;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
                return bufferedImage;
        }

        static void prUsage() {
                System.err
                                .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie [-w <width>] [-h <height>] [-f <frame rate>] [-o <output URL>] -i <input JPEG files dir Path>");
                // System.exit(-1);
        }

        /**
         * Create a media locator from the given string.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

                MediaLocator ml;

                if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
                        return ml;

                if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
                        if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                                return ml;
                } else {
                        String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                        + File.separator + url;
                        if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                                return ml;
                }
                return null;
        }

        // /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // Inner classes.
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
         * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
         */
        class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

                ImageSourceStream streams[];

                ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                                Vector<String> images) {
                        streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
                        streams[0] = new PngImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
                }

                public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
                }

                public MediaLocator getLocator() {
                        return null;
                }

                /**
                 * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
                 * without a container format.
                 */
                public String getContentType() {
                        return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
                }

                public void connect() {
                }

                public void disconnect() {
                }

                public void start() {
                }

                public void stop() {
                }

                /**
                 * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
                 */
                public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
                        return streams;
                }

                /**
                 * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
                 * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
                 */
                public Time getDuration() {
                        return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
                }

                public Object[] getControls() {
                        return new Object[0];
                }

                public Object getControl(String type) {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        /**
         * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
         */
        class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

                Vector<String> images;
                int width, height;
                VideoFormat format;

                int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
                boolean ended = false;

                public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                                Vector<String> images) {
                        this.width = width;
                        this.height = height;
                        this.images = images;

                        format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                                        height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                                        (float) frameRate);
                }

                /**
                 * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
                 */
                public boolean willReadBlock() {
                        return false;
                }

                /**
                 * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
                 * data.
                 */
                public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

                        // Check if we've finished all the frames.
                        if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                                // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                                System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                                buf.setEOM(true);
                                buf.setOffset(0);
                                buf.setLength(0);
                                ended = true;
                                return;
                        }

                        String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
                        nextImage++;

                        System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

                        // Open a random access file for the next image.
                        RandomAccessFile raFile;
                        raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

                        byte data[] = null;

                        // Check the input buffer type & size.

                        if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                                data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

                        // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
                        if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                                data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                                buf.setData(data);
                        }

                        // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
                        raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

                        System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

                        buf.setOffset(0);
                        buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
                        buf.setFormat(format);
                        buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

                        // Close the random access file.
                        raFile.close();
                }

                /**
                 * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
                 */
                public Format getFormat() {
                        return format;
                }

                public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
                        return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
                }

                public long getContentLength() {
                        return 0;
                }

                public boolean endOfStream() {
                        return ended;
                }

                public Object[] getControls() {
                        return new Object[0];
                }

                public Object getControl(String type) {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        class PngImageSourceStream extends ImageSourceStream {

              public PngImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                  Vector<String> images) {
                super(width, height, frameRate, images);

                // configure the new format as RGB format
                format = new RGBFormat(new Dimension(width, height),
                    Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray, frameRate, 
                                              24, // 24 bits per pixel
                                              1, 2, 3); // red, green and blue masks when data are in the form of byte[]
              }

              public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

                // Check if we've finished all the frames.
                if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                  // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                  System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                  buf.setEOM(true);
                  buf.setOffset(0);
                  buf.setLength(0);
                  ended = true;
                  return;
                }

                String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
                nextImage++;

                System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

                // read the PNG image
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));
                boolean hasAlpha = image.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
                Dimension size = format.getSize();

                // convert 32-bit RGBA to 24-bit RGB
                byte[] imageData = convertTo24Bit(hasAlpha, image.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, size.width, size.height, (int[]) null));
                buf.setData(imageData);

                System.err.println("    read " + imageData.length + " bytes.");

                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength(imageData.length);
                buf.setFormat(format);
                buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);
              }

              private void convertIntByteToByte(int[] src, int srcIndex, byte[] out, int outIndex) {
                // Note: the int[] returned by bufferedImage.getRaster().getPixels()
                // is an int[]
                // where each int is the value for one color i.e. the first 4 ints
                // contain the RGBA values for the first pixel
                int r = src[srcIndex];
                int g = src[srcIndex + 1];
                int b = src[srcIndex + 2];

                out[outIndex] = (byte) (r & 0xFF);
                out[outIndex + 1] = (byte) (g & 0xFF);
                out[outIndex + 2] = (byte) (b & 0xFF);
              }

              private byte[] convertTo24Bit(boolean hasAlpha, int[] input) {
                int dataLength = input.length;
                int newSize = (hasAlpha ? dataLength * 3 / 4 : dataLength);
                byte[] convertedData = new byte[newSize];

                // for every 4 int values of the original array (RGBA) write 3
                // bytes (RGB) to the output array
                // if there is no alpha (i.e. RGB image) then just convert int to byte
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dataLength; i += 3, j += 3) {
                  convertIntByteToByte(input, i, convertedData, j);
                  if (hasAlpha) {
                    i++; // skip an extra byte if the original image has an
                        // extra int for transparency
                  }
                }
                return convertedData;
              }

            }
}
```

And I make the video doing the following

```
public void makeVideo (String movFile) throws MalformedURLException {

    JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();

    Vector<String> imgList = new Vector <String>();

    File f = new File(JavCapture.tmpLocation + "\\tmp\\");
    File[] fileList = f.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        imgList.add(fileList[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }

    MediaLocator ml;

    if ((ml = imageToMovie.createMediaLocator(movFile)) == null) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    setWidth();
    setHeight();
    imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, (1000/125), imgList, ml);

}
```

Comment: Where in that source are the PNG files converted to JPEG?

Comment: You'll have to transcode it into another format if the codec it uses isn't widely supported enough for you.

Comment: The PNG files are not converted, if you look at my other question that other use helped me get the JpegImagesToMovies to work with .png files.

Comment: Have yu tried changing the content descriptor?

Comment: @MadProgrammer its not working even you change content descriptor to `MSVIDEO`